# How do you use PHP and SQL to submit table data to another table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a table of flights and I am using a loop to print out the flights information along with a submit button, the button that is clicked is the data that is submitted, what is the best way to go about this as this does not work. It knows what button is clicked but the SQL is not performed to insert the data to my basket

```
<?php
           $dbQuery=$db->prepare("select * from flights");
           $dbQuery->execute();
           $index = 1;
           while ($dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
           echo "<div>".
                "<div class=\"col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature\">".
                "<div class=\"thumbnail\">".
                "<img src=\"img/aeroplane.png\" alt=\"\">".
                "<div class=\"caption\">".
                "<h3>$dbRow[1] to $dbRow[2]</h3>".
                "<p>£$dbRow[3]</p>".
                "<p>".
                "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">".
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"submit\" />".
                "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" id=\"$index-submit\"type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"$index\">".
                "</form>".
                "</p>".
                "</div>".
                "</div>".
                "</div>".
                "</div>";

                if(isset($_POST['action'])){
                  //echo '<br />The ' . $_POST['submit'] . ' submit button was pressed<br />';
                  $dbQuery=$db->prepare("insert into basket values (null, :userID, :flightTo to :flightFrom, :flightPrice, 'N')");
                  $dbParams = array('userID'=>$userID,'fightTo'=>$dbRow[1],'fightFrom'=>$dbRow[2],'flightPrice'=>$dbRow[3]);
                  $dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
                  }

                $index++;
        }
```

Comment: put post action code out side of loop

Comment: I tried that there now, however it is still not passing the sql statement the correct dbRow for flight name and price so I can insert it into my database

Answer (score 0):

You repeated your insertion code in while loop, this doesn't look good, I just wrote an approach using ajax can solve your problem. you can follow this code, I have written it very clearly.

## main page

```
<!-- generate html rows as your requirement in php -->
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col1 col-md-1">test1</div>
                <div class="col2 col-md-1">test2</div>
                <div class="col3 col-md-1">test3</div>
                <div class="col4 col-md-1">test4</div>
                <div class="col-md-1"> <button type="button" class="use-address" >Save</button></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col1 col-md-1">test5</div>
                <div class="col2 col-md-1">test6</div>
                <div class="col3 col-md-1">test7</div>
                <div class="col4 col-md-1">test8</div>
                <div class="col-md-1"> <button type="button" class="use-address" >Save</button></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col1 col-md-1">test9</div>
                <div class="col2 col-md-1">test10</div>
                <div class="col3 col-md-1">test11</div>
                <div class="col4 col-md-1">test12</div>
                <div class="col-md-1"> <button type="button" class="use-address" >Save</button></div>
        </div>
</div>

<script src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".use-address").click(function() {
                var val1 = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('.col1').text();
                var val2 = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('.col2').text();
                var val3 = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('.col3').text();
                var val4 = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('.col4').text();
                $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'service.php',
                        data:{val1:val1,val2:val2,val3:val3,val4:val4,action:'saveData'},
                        success:function(response){
                                alert(response);
                        }
                });
        });
})
</script>
```

## service.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'saveData'){
    echo $_POST['val1'],", ",$_POST['val2'],", ",$_POST['val3'],", ",$_POST['val4'];
    //write here your mysql insertion code and return successfull message
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect